# Recreating a folder structure inside a Zip file with Java - Empty folders

Tags: java, zip, nio

I'm tried several ways to zip a directory structure in a zip file with Java. Don't matter if I use `ZipOutputStream` or the Java NIO zip `FileSystem`, I just can't add empty folders to the zip file.

I tried with unix zip, and it works as expected, so I discarded a possibly zip-format issue.

I could also do a little workaround, adding an empty file inside the folders, but I don't really want to do that.

Is there a way to add empty folders in zip files using java API's?

---

**EDIT**: Based on answers and comments, [this is pretty much the solution I got](https://gist.github.com/caarlos0/5ad0831a93192bd0cb38).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java NIO makes this as easy as working with a normal file system.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path zipfile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\me.user\\Downloads\\myfile.zip");

    try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipfile, null);) {
        Path extFile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\me.user\\Downloads\\countries.csv"); // from normal file system
        Path directory = zipfs.getPath("/some/directory"); // from zip file system
        Files.createDirectories(directory);
        Files.copy(extFile, directory.resolve("zippedFile.csv"));
    }
}
```

Given a `myfile.zip` file in the given directory, the `newFileSystem` call will detect the file type (.zip mostly gives it away in this case) and create a `ZipFileSystem`. Then you can just create paths (directories or files) in the zip file system and use the Java NIO `Files` api to create and copy files.

The above will create the directory structure `/some/directory` at the root of the zip file and that directory will contain the zipped file.

Comment: Yep, but I want to create a zip with empty folders only... thanks

Comment: @caarlos0 Then don't copy any files into it...Just use `Files.createDirectories`.